# sending javascript variable (from knockout.js) to php and return result

Tags: php, javascript, knockout.js

How can I go about accomplishing the following behavior.

1. upon getting an input from a knockout.js form send the variable to a page to be handled. The page uses PHP
2. The PHP page receives the input from the knockout.js form and runs some calculations and then returns the result
3. The variable is then received back on the original page and is then displayed via knockout

For example, say I have the following

```
//knockout_form.js
self.addItem = function() {
    var itemNum = self.newItem; //variable received from knockout form

    var returnedVariable = ???? **send itemNum to processing.php which will then return it**

    self.itemNumbers.push(new ItemEntry(retunredVariable, "$20.00")); //
}
```

I know that jQuery/Ajax can be used to post to processing.php, but how do I return the calculated data from processing.php back to the javascript page?

**edit below. The data appears to be sent to processing.php (shows up in the network tab) but the alert isn't showing.**

```
// Operations
self.addItem = function() {
    var itemNum = self.newItem;

    $.getJSON("processing.php?itemNum=" + itemNum),function(data) {
        alert(data); //this does not appear
        self.itemNumbers.push(new ItemEntry(data.result, "$20.00"));
    }
}
```

Here's the php

```
//$result = $_GET['itemNum'];
$result = "test";  //set it just to be sure it's working
echo json_encode(array("result" => $result));
```

Comment: Check into AJAX functionality of jquery.

Comment: Knock out can handle JSON data via AJAX: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knockout doesn't have any special way of doing ajax calls itself, typically you would use jQuery. See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html.

So something like:

```
self.addItem = function() {
    var itemNum = self.newItem;

    $.getJSON("processing.php?itemNum=" + itemNum,function(data) {
        self.itemNumbers.push(new ItemEntry(data.result, "$20.00"));
    });
}
```

This assume that your PHP script is outputting valid JSON. Something like:

```
<?php
$result = doCalculations($_GET['itemNum']);
echo json_encode(array("result" => $result));
?>
```

This is untested, but you get the idea.

Comment: How does the php get sent back to the javascript page once it's received and processed? I see the JSON bit, but where is it actually send it back? Is it just the echo that does it?

Comment: Uh, see that "echo" statement above? That's taking the results of json_encode() and spitting it out. That will be the `data` of the ajax callback.

Comment: The data seems to be sent to processing.php (I checked the network and the value is being sent), but nothing is being returned. Any suggestions?

Comment: Whatever your php script outputs is what will be returned. Load processing.php?itemNum=X in your browser manually. Ensure that your own php script is outputting valid json. If it's not, you have a problem in your php code, nothing to do with ajax.

Comment: I set $result = "test" on processing.php and tried to return that. Nothing happens

Comment: What do you get in your browser, exactly, when you load processing.php?

Comment: When I open processing.php {"result":"test"} is displayed. (I set $result = test")

Comment: Excellent. Now in the $.getJSON callback, do alert(data) to show that you have that output in javascript. You should be all set.

Comment: The alert doesn't appear, unless I placed in the wrong position. I updated my code above to reflect the changes you suggested

Comment: You have a closing parenthesis after the itemNum, before the callback function. Remove that. Look at the code I gave you.

Comment: When I remove that parenthesis the form stops working. Shouldn't that parenthesis go somewhere else then? There's 1 less closing parenthesis than opening the way you have it.

Comment: it goes at the very end of the getJSON call, I've updated my answer